# Created tag: Islam

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created the [islam](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam) tag with the following short description (still in peer review):

> Questions relating to Islamic culture and traditions and how they pertain to the workplace

We've had a few questions from Muslim individuals who had had trouble interacting in other cultural contexts because of their religion - and thus not covered by [middle-east](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-east). For this reason I believe it's a good addition to our taxonomic vocabulary.

To be clear, I see Islam as a **culture**, not a religion, and it is the culture that interacts with itself and the rest of the world. The tag is about the culture - which is largely uniform.

Let's see if we can make it viable. I remember a particular question answered best by Kilisi which would be a good example for it - but I wanted to get the community's opinion before I go on an edit spree.

Comment: I answered an Islamic question?

Comment: @Kilisi The one about the guy not wanting to shake hands with women. Maybe he wasn't Muslim, but I can't remember

Comment: Yeah, I remember something like that

Comment: We do have an [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) stack that covers cultural questions.

Comment: @Snow We do. And maths.SE has a `cryptography` tag, for which we also have a site :) My intention for this tag was the cross-section of culture and business, specifically observant Muslims in foreign cultures

Comment: Uhmm... both islam and middle east have just one question... I wonder if it's worth creating a tag for a single question, as well as if it's worth separating religions as Kilisi mentioned...

Comment: For the question you tagged, we should probably just leave it at "for religious reasons" and remove the religion-specific context - that's only distracting from the issue (there are currently 2 comments on the question and 1 answer that mention the religion, but none of them have anything to do with the workplace). At that point it wouldn't make sense to add a religion-specific tag.

Comment: @Dukeling That's a good solution

Comment: I finally found the handshake question, I didn't answer it at all...

Comment: @Kilisi Really? I thought it was you... My bad

Comment: I wonder how they greet women? They can't bow and can't shake hands.

Comment: So... based on the answer received, should this islam tag be removed from the one post it is on as of now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A month after the posting of this Discussion, seems that the consensus is against the use of the Islam tag (and the division in religions, in general).

Thus, I took the liberty to **remove the sole instance of that tag**, and replaced it with the [religion](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) one (added excerpt also), as to indicate religion is still a relevant aspect in the context of the question, while avoiding any framing or negative situations that may come from dividing it to a specific religion (avoiding baits, controversy, and biased judgments unrelated to the workplace situation).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think we should start separating religions.

So while a tag for religion makes sense to me, separate ones don't. Should you separate into denominations, general beliefs, specifics? Who would make the decisions. Who's perception of what a religion is would be used anyway? An athiests?

Many denominations believe there is only one religion in the World, and a whole bunch of Satan inspired cults which includes other denominations that outsiders might consider the same as them.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree with the general theme - religion is something that can be absolutely pertinent to navigating the workplace (it's a protected characteristic in multiple locales for example) I'm not sure creating a tag for specific religions is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Islam gets a lot of bad rap - as do many other religions.

I'm not sure adding a tag to make it easier for people who wish to stir the pot for a particular religion is the right approach.

I'm also not sure what other purpose the tag would serve - is there a need to let someone find all the "Islam" questions here? Would tagging a question about bowing "Islam" be helpful, and what if I'm, say, a Sikh, who according to wiki "only bow to their gurus". Do we need to then tag this question as Sikh too, or have a separate (but otherwise identical) question for Sikhs?

Also you probably want to capitalise your "islam" tag to be "Islam".

Comment: I was unaware that you could capitalize tags, that would be appropriate. Yes, it would be a good idea to filter all Islam questions... if you're interested in Islam, as is the case for every other tag :) I'm not too worried about the potential ill effects of tagging questions so because I have faith in our moderators and the community (and if someone's hell bent to stir the pot, they'll find ways to do it).

Answer (score 4):

**I don't agree on creating such tag**

First, we can see that the [middle-east tag only has 1 question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-east), which could even be focused down to the actual country and burninate the middle-east tag altogether...

Second, we already have a tag that could be used here: [religion](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion). It has 7 questions and all of them highly voted and viewed. It also overcomes the issue of separating religions, as it can be used regardless the specific religious beliefs the post covers.

We also have the tag [culture](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture). This has 57 posts, and although it currently lacks excerpt and wiki, I see the posts it contains are related to cultural and even religious beliefs and practices.

Bottom line... I don't recommend creating such tag. **I think it is better if we gave the religion and culture tag description and wiki and start using them** on posts that relate to any religious/cultural beliefs or practices that interact with the workplace, when they apply.